# Error while copying objects from one S3 bucket to another s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to copy objects from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket, i see below error,

aws s3 cp s3://cloud-test/aggs s3://core-templates/

An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "aggs/" does not exist

Comment: Expand more on what you have tried and how your environment is setup.  Try not to make assumptions when asking for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, aws s3 cp s3://cloud-test/aggs s3://core-templates/aggs/ --recursive